# In Laravel Queue get the response immediately and run the job in background without using worker?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm working on laravel queue for 1500 entries which i have to insert in database table. i want to display the response that 'refund started' and run the job in background i have used dispatch(), dispatch_sync(), Bus::dispatchNow() etc. but by using **dispatch() or Bus::dispatchNow()** get the response quickly but have to start the job with command "php artisan queue:work"
By using **dispatch_sync()** the job started immediately but i don't get the response and have to wait for the job to complete.

Thats the controller having function **refundWallet**

```
public function refundWallet(Request $request)
    {
        $refundedOrder = RefundedOrders::create([
            'data' => $request->all(),
            'status' => 'in_process'
        ]);
        $requestall = $request->all();
        $requestData = new Refund_Order_Queue_Process($requestall, $refundedOrder->id);
        // $requestData->handle();
        Bus::dispatchNow($requestData);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Refund process started.',
            'refundRequestId' => $refundedOrder->id,
        ]);

    }
}
```

when i hit the api get the following response immediately:

```
return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Refund process started.',
            'refundRequestId' => $refundedOrder->id,
        ]);
```

But job does not start itself i have to use 'php artisan queue:work'
**I want to get the response immediately and run the job automatically in the background.**

Comment: local environment you start your queue self in most simple cases, but on your server setup run it with a supervisor or similar https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: right now im working on local not production

Comment: Then you need to have a process running php artisan queue:listen and it will do it

Comment: is there any way to automate that process on local?

Comment: why does it matter? it seems like a small inconvenience, if you want an environment that is closer to what you would run on production set up docker with it. The documentation has examples of how to do it locally on linux machines atleast.